# Google Analitycs Ecommerce don't register the transaction

Tags: typescript, google-analytics

i've a big problem, i don't understand because the module ecommerce of GA don't send the transaction.
When the programs return from the ecomerce there is an error in the GA analitycs console.

[image]

There is the Typescript code who call the ecommerce:

{

```
    ga('require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': transactionId,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'revenue': price
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': transactionId,
        'name': Testname,
        'category': 'Test',         
        'price': price,                
        'quantity': '1'  
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');

}
```

When i'm in debugging mode i see that parameters are correct.

I guess you can advice me, because i don't have idea what is the road for the success of this problem.
THKS

Comment: Thats not a google analtyics error.  Thats a typescript error  it could be related to anything in your file

Comment: Yes but i think that error occurred when there is the call try, the file eccomerce wasn't download and don't find the method...

Comment: You'll need to provide more debugging information.